# Find the Laurent series in an annulus

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the function $f(z) = \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{z+1}$ for which I would like to find the Laurent series in the annulus $1 < |z-i| < \sqrt{2}$

This is what I did

first, let $w = z-i, 0 < w < \sqrt{2}$

Pluging this into the expression for $f(z)$ we have

$f(z) = \frac{1}{w+1} + \frac{1}{w+i+1} = \frac{1}{w+1} + \frac{1}{w+i}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{w+i}}$

Using the geometric series formula we have

$f(z) = \frac{1}{w+i} + \frac{1}{w+i}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{-1}{w+i})^n$

Which turns out to be

$\frac{1}{z^2} - \frac{1}{z^3}$ + ...

However I'am told this is incorrect but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summand $\dfrac{1}{z+1}$ is holomorphic in the disk $\{ z : \lvert z-i\rvert < \sqrt{2}\}$, so you should expand it into its Taylor series around $i$.

Also, you should not expand the summands into powers of $w+i = z$, but into powers of $w = z-i$, so you should get a Laurent expansion

$$\frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{z+1} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n (z-i)^n.$$

In the annulus $1 < \lvert z-i\rvert < \sqrt{2}$, the first summand, $\dfrac{1}{z}$ contributes the coefficients for the negative powers of $z-i$, the second for the positive powers (both contribute to the coefficient of $(z-i)^0$).

Answer (score 0):

Be careful: You have to specify *the point about which* you are finding a Laurent series. I'm guessing you want it about $z=i$, i.e. in powers of $z = w+i$. (Pedantic: You want $1 < |w| < \sqrt{2}$.)

Subbing in,
$$ 
\begin{align}
 f(z) & = \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{z+1} \\
      & = \frac{1}{i+w} + \frac{1}{w+i+1}
\end{align}
$$
which I prefer to write as 
$$ \begin{align}
& (i+w)^{-1} + (1+i + w)^{-1} \\
=&  w^{-1} (1+w^{-1}i)^{-1} + (1+i)^{-1} \left(1+\frac{w}{1+i}\right)^{-1}
\end{align} $$
Now... for your annulus, you have $|w|>1$, so you can expand the first bracket as a binomial series. And also $|w|<\sqrt{2}$, so $|w/(1+i)| < 1$, so you can also expand the second bracket. You end up with two series in $w = (z-i)$ which you put together.

Hope that helps.